# Implement strategy for Jacks or Better Video

Tags: code-golf

You are dealt five cards from a single deck. Implement a strategy for [Jacks or Better Video Poker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_poker#Jacks_or_Better) that has an expected revenue of *at least* [99.46%](http://wizardofodds.com/jacksorbetter/simple.html). Output the cards you want to hold.

The shortest code wins.

You are not required to implement the suggested strategy. Optimum play is also acceptable.

**Input** is read from standard input, **output** is written to standard output. Cards are identified as pairs of number (2,...,9,T,J,Q,K,A) and suit (S,H,D,C - spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs): 3C - three of clubs, QH - queen of hearts.

[image]

Examples:

```
$ ./jacks                               |
3C JC 5C QC 3H                          |<< input
3C 3H                                   |<< output
$ ./jacks                               |
3C 4C 5C 6C 7C                          |<< input
3C 4C 5C 6C 7C                          |<< output
```

Comment: Is this a single deck?  It simplifies the logic because, for example, if a hand is 4 to a flush it can't have a 3 of a kind.

Comment: @Keith: Single deck.

Comment: Can we use T instead of 10, it would simplify things greatly!

Comment: @mellamokb: My bad. Yes. I'm updating now.

Answer (score 3):

I did it!!!

```
import java.io.*;
// 427 lines 200
public class Base {

    static char suit (String tokens) {  return  tokens.charAt (1); }
    public static char num (String tokens) { return tokens.charAt (0);}

    public static void checkPair (String [] tokens)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; ++a)
        for (int b = a+1; b < 5; ++b) 
            if (num (tokens [a]) == num (tokens [b]))
                System.out.print (tokens [a] + " " + tokens [b]);
    }

    public static void checkThreeKind (String [] tokens)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a)
            if (num (tokens [a]) == num (tokens [a+1]))
                for (int b = 2; b < 5; ++b) 
                    if (num (tokens [a]) == num (tokens [b]))
                        System.out.print (tokens [a] + " " + tokens [a+1] + " " + tokens [b]);
    }

    static void checkTwoPair (String [] tokens)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
            //First Increment is pair 1 2, followed by 1 3, 1 4, and 1, 5 then 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, then 3 4, 3 5 then 4 5
            if (num (tokens [i]) == num (tokens [j]))
                for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
                    for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
                        if ((i != y) && (j != x) && (y != x) && (i != j))
                            if (num (tokens [y]) == num (tokens [x]))
                                if ((tokens [i] != tokens [j]) && (tokens [i] != tokens [y]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [y]) &&
                                        (tokens [i] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [y] != tokens [x]))
                                    eblock (tokens);
    }

    static void checkHighFlush (String [] tokens)
    {
        if (suit (tokens [0]) == suit (tokens [1]) &&
            suit (tokens [0]) == suit (tokens [2]) && 
            suit (tokens [0]) == suit (tokens [3]) && 
            suit (tokens [0]) == suit (tokens [4]))
        {
            String outputString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                outputString  += tokens [i] + " ";
            System.out.println (outputString);
            System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            for (int j= 1; j<= 4; j++)
                //First Increment is pair 1 2, followed by 1 3, 1 4, and 1, 5 then 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, then 3 4, 3 5 then 4 5
                if (suit (tokens [i]) == suit (tokens [j]))
                    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
                        for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
                            if ((i != y) && (j != x) && (y != x) && (i != j))
                            {
                                if (suit (tokens [i]) == suit (tokens [x]) &&
                                        suit (tokens [i]) == suit (tokens [y]))
                                {
                                    if ((tokens [i] != tokens [j]) && (tokens [i] != tokens [y]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [y]) &&
                                            (tokens [i] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [y] != tokens [x]))
                                        eblock (tokens);
                                }
                            }
    }

     static void checkFourKind (String [] tokens)
     {
        if (num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [1]))
        {
            if (num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [2])) 
                if (num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [3]) || num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [4]))
                    eblock (tokens);
            if (num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [3]))
                if (num (tokens [0]) == num (tokens [4]))
                    eblock (tokens);
        }
        if (num (tokens [1]) == num (tokens [2]))
            if (num (tokens [1]) == num (tokens [3])) 
                if (num (tokens [1]) == num (tokens [4])) 
                    eblock (tokens);
    }

    static void checkStraight (String [] tokens)
    {
        int [] ints = new int [5];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {   
            switch (num (tokens [i]))        {
            case 'T': ints [i] = 10;
            case 'J': ints [i] = 11;
            case 'Q': ints [i] = 12;
            case 'K': ints [i] = 13;
            case 'A': ints [i] = 14;
            default:  ints [i] = num (tokens [i]) - '0';
        }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        for (int j= 1; j<= 4; j++)
            //First Increment is pair 1 2, followed by 1 3, 1 4, and 1, 5 then 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, then 3 4, 3 5 then 4 5
            if ((ints [i]+1) == ints [i+1])
                for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
                    for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
                        if ((i != y) && (j != x) && (y != x) && (i != j))
                        {
                            if (ints[i] + 2 == ints[y] && ints[i] + 3 == ints [x])
                            {
                                if ((tokens [i] != tokens [j]) && (tokens [i] != tokens [y]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [y]) &&
                                        (tokens [i] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [j] != tokens [x]) && (tokens [y] != tokens [x]))
                                {
                                    for (int a : new int[] {i, j, y, x})
                                        System.out.print (tokens [a] + " ");    
                                    System.out.println ();
                                    System.exit (0);
                                }
                            }
                            java.util.Arrays.sort (ints);
                            if (( (ints [i]+1 == ints [j]) && (ints [i]+3 == ints [y]) && (ints [i]+4 == ints [x])))
                            {
                                for (int a : new int[] {i, j, y, x})
                                    System.out.print (tokens [a] + " ");    
                                System.out.println ();
                                System.exit (0);
                            }
                        }
    }

    static void checkHighCard (String [] tokens)
    {
        int [] ints = new int [5];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {   
            switch (num (tokens [i]))        {
            case 'T': ints [i] = 10;
            case 'J': ints [i] = 11;
            case 'Q': ints [i] = 12;
            case 'K': ints [i] = 13;
            case 'A': ints [i] = 14;
            default:  ints [i] = num (tokens [i]) - '0';
        }
        }
        int marker = 0;
        if (ints [0] > ints [1]) marker = 1;
        if (ints [1] > ints [2]) marker = 2;
        if (ints [2] > ints [3]) marker = 3;
        if (ints [3] > ints [4]) marker = 4;
        System.out.println (tokens [marker]);
    }

    static void eblock (String[] tokens) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.print (tokens [i] + " ");
        System.out.println ();
        System.exit (0);
    }

    static void checkFullHouse (String [] tokens)
    {
        String [] test = new String [5];
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        test [i] = tokens [i];
        for (int i = 0; i <=4; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            if (num (test [i]) == num (tokens [j]))
                counter++;
        }
        if (counter > 1) 
            sum++;
        counter = 0;
        }
        if (sum == 5) eblock (tokens);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        String inputString = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)).readLine ();
        String [] tokens = inputString.split (" ");
        java.util.Arrays.sort (tokens);
        checkFourKind (tokens);
        checkHighFlush (tokens);
        checkFullHouse (tokens);
        checkStraight (tokens);
        checkTwoPair (tokens);
        checkThreeKind (tokens);
        checkPair (tokens);
        checkHighCard (tokens);
    }   
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the answer be golfed? even if there are no competitors, it's still code-golf

Comment: I made a first step towards golfing: Reduced from about 12k to about 6k. Roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: This was my first post.  Thanks for editing, did I have it right?  How does one get points!?!